# ElasticSearch Aggregation on nested field with bucketing on parent id

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Following is my doc structure

```
'Order': {
    u'properties': {
        u'order_id': {u'type': u'integer'},
        'Product': {
            u'properties': {
                u'product_id': {u'type': u'integer'},                
                u'product_category': {'type': 'text'},                
            },
            u'type': u'nested'
        }
    }
}
```

Doc1

```
"Order": {
    "order_id": "1",
    "Product": [
        {
            "product_id": "1", 
            "product_category": "category_1"
        }, 
        {
            "product_id": "2", 
            "product_category": "category_2"
        },
        {
            "product_id": "3", 
            "product_category": "category_2"
        },
    ] 
}
```

Doc2

```
"Order": {

    "order_id": "2",
    "Product": [
        {
            "product_id": "4", 
            "product_category": "category_1"
        }, 
        {
            "product_id": "1", 
            "product_category": "category_1"
        },
        {
            "product_id": "2", 
            "product_category": "category_2"
        },
    ] 
}
```

I want to get following output

```
"aggregations": {
    "Order": [
        {
            "order_id": "1"                
            "category_counts": [
                {
                    "category_1": 1
                },
                {
                    "category_2": 2
                },
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "order_id": "1"                
            "category_counts": [
                {
                    "category_1": 2
                },
                {
                    "category_2": 1
                },
            ]
        }, 
    ]
}
```

I tried using nested aggregation

```
"aggs": {
    "Product-nested": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "Product"
        }
        "aggs": {
            "category_counts": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "Product.product_category"
                }
            }
        }, 
    }
}
```

It does not give output for each order but gives combined output for all orders

```
{
    "Product-nested": {
        "category_counts": [
            "category_1": 3,
            "category_2": 3
        ]
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

- How to get the desired output in above scenario?
- What if instead of single product_category I have an array of
  product_categories then how will we achieve the same in this
  scenario?

I am using elasticsearch >= 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but i dont think its the best one..

you can make a terms aggregation on the "order_id" field, then  a sub nestes aggregation on "Product.product_category".

somthing like this :

{

"aggs": {

```
"all-order-id": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "order_id",
    "size": 10
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Product-nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Product"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "all-products-in-order-id": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Product.product_category"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

sorry its lock bit messy i'm not so good with this answer editor